# Active workbook and select issues, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I have a form where I want to populate two listboxes with the data stored in Roses and Customers worksheets. The line of code bwith the **** below is what is giving me trouble.

```
Private Sub UserForm_activate()

    Application.Workbooks("xx.xlsm").Activate

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Customers").Range("B2").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
    'loop through the customer table list
        lstCustomers.AddItem ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    *****ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Roses").Range("A3").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
    'loop through the roses table list
        lstProducts.AddItem ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Error: Select method of range class failed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

Select the worksheet and cell sequentially rather than in a single line.

Do not use IsEmpty() to test for an un-filled cell.  Rather use ActiveCell.Value=""